# Matching Duplicate values with unique attributes in a horizontal excel spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting, duplicates, matching

Hopefully someone has had my problem before.  I'm in the process of building an Excel model that sorts the prices that a certain product was sold for and the sales associated with that price. One spreadsheet houses the data and another sorts that data by sales and then matches the price that it sold for.

The problem is that there are cases where the number of sales are the same but the prices are different.  In these cases, the first price is duplicated by the when the number of sales are the same. See below for a visual. I've looked tirelessly for a solution but because the formula needs to be designed horizontal

This sales volume sorting formula `=IFERROR(LARGE('2016 Data Tab '!$B3:$BY3,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76}),"")`

this formula matches the price with the sales. This is where I'm having the problem `=IFERROR(INDEX(DataTableLanes16,$A3*$C$1,MATCH('2016 Input Lanes '!C3,'2016 Data Tab '!$A3:$BY3,0)),"")`

See the pictures below:

This is where the data is housed:
[image: This is where the data is housed]

This is where the data is sorted by sales:
[image: This is where the data is sorted by sales]

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

James

Comment: Why not just sort the data (`Data►Sort`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible to just sort the data.  Excel can sort left to right.

If you **MUST** use formulas, you need to calculate the rank of each sales number in a manner that accounts for duplicates.

You can add a "helper row".  Name it `SalesRank`

You can then use this formula in (as in the screenshot), B4

```
B4: =RANK(B3,Sales,0)+COUNTIF($B$3:B3,B3)-1
```

and fill right

For the desired results, we first list the sales in descending order:

```
B9: =LARGE(Sales,COLUMNS($A:A))
```

and fill right

And then, for the associated prices:

```
B10:  =INDEX(Price,1,MATCH(COLUMNS($A:A),SalesRank,0))
```

In the above formulas:

```
| Price         | Refers to:    | =Sheet3!$B$2:$K$2     |
| Sales         | Refers to:    | =Sheet3!$B$3:$K$3     |
| SalesRank     | Refers to:    | =Sheet3!$B$4:$K$4     |
```

[image]

Comment: This worked really well. Thanks a lot for your help!